# Laravel - errors for multiple forms

Tags: php, forms, laravel, error-handling

i found a few answers on this question, but i do not know how to apply them to my code. I want to display errors only for the form which had a faulty request. My problem is that currently it displays errors both on login and register form, no matter which one was faulty.

My UserController@postRegister:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)  
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|min:3|max:50|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',                    
        'password' => 'required|min:4|max:120',
        ]);
```

My dashboard view:

```
@if ($errors->any())
{
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <p>{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
}
@endif
```

How can i make this display error for a specific form only, but on the same page as other forms?

Comment: name your form and check if(isset($_POST['login_submit']) {then error section} or if(isset($_POST['register_submit']) {then error section}
Error section will be displayed only on submission of login form or register based on your if condition. You can use the name of the submit button or the name of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can display form validation error messages separately and this thing will explain you better [this demonstrate video](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-2/episodes/4).